# Misunderstanding of async/await evaluation details

Tags: javascript, async-await

I try to follow the ECMAScript spec to find out how `async/await` do its work and encountered some hurdle.

Let's suppose there is such code:

```
function boo() {
    return 1;
}

async function foo() {
    let result = await boo();
    return result;
}

foo();
```

So let's start to track step by step what must be done under the hood:

1. Running [`[[Call]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) internal method of `foo()`, that suspends the current execution context (`callerContext`), creates new one (`calleeContext`) and pushes it onto the execution context stack. We have the execution context stack of this look: `callerContext < calleeContext -- running`.
2. The next step is a `foo()` evaluation (that is `AsyncFunctionBody` associated with it), that in effect is [`EvaluateAsyncFunctionBody`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-evaluateasyncfunctionbody). This routine, in turn, calls [`AsyncFunctionStart`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start). It creates a copy of the running execution context - `asyncContext` - and pushes it onto the stack, which now is as follows: `callerContext < calleeContext < asyncContext -- running`. `calleeContext` is left anxious to receive the result of `asyncContext` evaluation later (step 10).
3. As it was prescribed in `AsyncFunctionStart`, `asyncContext` evaluates `FunctionBody`of `foo()`. The `await` expression is met along the way. It is [defined](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-async-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation) to get the result of `boo()` firstly and subsequently call [`Await`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#await) routine with `1` as an argument.
4. `Await` creates a promise resolved with `1` and performs its `then()`, so that the promise can notify of its fulfilled value and this value would exposed as the result of the `await` expression. But for now `asyncContext` is removed from the execution context stack, which at the current time is `callerContext < calleeContext -- running`.

It is difficult to me to understand what is next due to happen. A promise takes the opportunity to notify its subscribers only when the execution context stack is empty because for the sake of it the [`Job`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-jobs) queue is involved. In the other hand, `caleeContext` is waiting for the result of `asyncContext` evaluation (step 10 of `AsyncFunctionStart`) and I can't find the place where both execution contexts (`calleeContext` and `callerContext`) removed from the stack. It seems like a deadlock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `caleeContext` is waiting for the result of `asyncContext` evaluation

Not really "waiting". As you said, the [`await` keyword](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#await) removes the `asyncContext` from the call stack, and returns<sup>1</sup> `undefined` in step 6 of [*AsyncFunctionStart*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start)<sup>2</sup>. After this is done, step 5 of [*EvaluateAsyncFunctionBody*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-evaluateasyncfunctionbody) does return the promise result. With this result, step 7 of [*[[Call]]*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) is done, and step 8 does "*Remove `calleeContext` from the execution context stack and restore `callerContext` as the running execution context.*". Now `foo()` has returned the promise.

The `callerContext` is finally removed from the stack in step 14 of [*ScriptEvaluation*](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) - it's the global `scriptContext`.

<sub>1: See also the NOTE (step 15) in *Await*: "*This returns to the evaluation of the operation that had most previously resumed evaluation of `asyncContext`.*"

2: See also the assertions (step 7 and 8) in *AsyncFunctionStart*: "*When we return here, `asyncContext` has already been removed from the execution context stack and `runningContext` is the currently running execution context. `result` is a normal completion with a value of `undefined`. [A] possible source of completion values [is]* Await".</sub>

Comment: Step 6 of  `AsyncFunctionStart`: *Let result be the value returned by the resumed computation. [of asyncContext]*
Step 12 of `Await`: *Remove asyncContext from the execution context stack and restore the execution context that is at the top of the execution context stack as the running execution context. [that is calleeContext]*
I can't get why is the following steps of `Await` (13 and so on) running on behalf of `calleeContext` while its associated code must wait for the result of resumed evaluation of `asyncContext`?

Comment: @Mergasov What do you mean by "associated code"?

Comment: *A new execution context is created whenever control is transferred from the executable code associated with the currently running execution context to executable code that is not associated with that execution context.* [9.4](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts). In fact, steps defined in 4 of `AsyncFunctionStart` (they subsequently call `Await`) is associated with `asyncContext`

Comment: In the other words, "associated code" is that which is executing while its execution context is running. So as it defined in the step 4 of  `AsyncFunctionStart` evaluating of `asyncFunctionBody` must be taken place while `asyncContext` is running. And I'm got completely confused when `Await` prescribes to remove `asyncContext` from the stack on the halfway. What's the next? Probably I understand all this wrong?

Comment: @Mergasov Ah, yes, but associated to what? The code associated with the `asyncContext` is paused and later resumed, without explicitly mentioning this in every algorithm where *Await* might be called. It doesn't busy-wait on anything, that's the whole trick of coroutines. The code associated with the `foo()` call doesn't wait for the result of the code associated with the `asyncContext`, it only runs until the `await` is met and control jumps back to where the coroutine resumption was started.

Comment: @Mergasov "*I'm got completely confused when* Await *prescribes to remove `asyncContext` from the stack on the halfway.*" - no, your understanding is good: the code associated with the asyncContext is indeed only halfway through. It's paused (suspended) in the middle of its execution, and can be resumed later - in the `onFulfillment`/`onRejection` handler of the promise. "*What's the next?*" - the execution of the code that started the partial resumption.

Comment: @Mergasov You can compare this with generators. The  `yield` keyword suspends the current execution context - somewhere in the middle of the generator function body - and "returns" (jumps back) to where the `.next()` method was called.